# Dynamic Checkbox from a txt file entry on a WinForm UI

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, checkbox, text-files

Good Morning;

Actually have 2 questions. My first is what is this called? A Program? A Module?

```
WhatIsThisCalled()
 {
   //workToBeDone
 }
```

I'm trying to create dynamic checkbox(s) from each entry in a text file. I'm trying to reuse the code so I have tried to create the module in a logic file. I feel like I've done this correctly, but I can't test it. I can not figure out how to reference

```
this.Controls.Add(chk[I]);
```

to the winForm I want to call it on. The error I get is about it being illegal in a static method. I'm only trying to clear the error (last one) so I can see if it will actually put the checkboxes onto the correct winForm Permissions.cs. Here is my Logic.cs module.

```
    public static void getPermText()
    {
        Stream fileStream = File.Open(dataFolder + PermFile, FileMode.Open);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream);

        string line = null;

        do
        {
            line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (line == null)
            {
                break;
            }

            string[] parts = line.Split('\n');

            try
        {

            int userCount;

            userCount = parts.Length;

            CheckBox[] chk = new CheckBox[userCount];
            int height = 1;
            int padding = 10;

            for (int i = 0; i <= userCount; i++)
            {
                chk[i] = new CheckBox();

                chk[i].Name = parts.ToString();

                chk[i].Text = parts.ToString();

                chk[i].TabIndex = i;

                chk[i].AutoCheck = true;

                chk[i].Bounds = new Rectangle(15, 30 + padding + height, 150, 22);

                this.Controls.Add(chk[i]);

                height += 22;

            }

        }

        catch
        {
        }
        } while (true);


    }
```

There is one global int userCount = 0; above that module. On Permissions.cs I have  this code (with no errors).

```
    public Permissions()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Permissions_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WidgetLogic.getPermText();
    }
```

Can anyone please direct me as to how, or if it is possible, to replace Permissions with this in a dynamic format?? I think??

Thank you very much in advance for all that look or help. I really appreciate it. Have a Great Day!! :)

Comment: `static` function: you cannot access any object within a static function, so `this` is not available in such `static` function. And sorry, your actual intention is not clear to answer. Maybe try rephrasing the question/add more code/screen shot desired etc?

Comment: Please see answer below by @shaharyar. That is what my question is. How do I access the targetForm. My apologies. I'm a very new Newb. Just trying to make it. :)

Comment: Your first question is an example of a `private` constructor, which are typically used in classes where everything is `static` and an empty one of these is meant to replace the default constructor, so the class cannot be instantiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tired very hard to understand what you wanted to say. I think you just want to reference the form where the `CheckBoxes` should create.

So you should better pass the reference the of the form on which you want to create the controls:

```
public static void getPermText(System.Windows.Forms.Form targetForm)
{
    //code
    targetForm.Controls.Add(chk[i]);  //changed "this" to "targetForm"
```

To call the method:

```
WidgetLogic.getPermText(this);  //here "this" refers to the current form
```

Now where ever you will call this method it will create the controls on your form (the one you're passing as the parameter).

Notify me if I got your question wrong.

Comment: Yes!! That is exactly what I want to do. I'll try your code shortly. Got pulled back into my real job :) @shaharyar do you think you might have an answer to my first question?? whatIsThat() called??

Comment: That is called a method or a function. But it should have a return type.

Comment: Bonus!! Thanks you. I thought method. I'm used to Excel. It's a function there so I guess I would not have guessed wrong. :) I'll let you know what happens. Thanks.

Comment: Brilliant!! That worked perfect. Now I have to go through the code to find out why the labels read system.form instead of the line in the file. Pretty sure I am not incrementing them is one problem. Thank You. I'll post the results here. Have a Great Day!! :-D

Comment: If you still have a problem but it doesn't relate to this question. You may ask another question for that specific problem