# Why is this for() not incrementing?

Tags: c#, winforms, for-loop, checkbox, increment

With great assistance I was able to write a dynamic checkbox to a winForm using this.

Ref: [Dynamic Checkbox from a txt file entry on a WinForm UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26362744/dynamic-checkbox-from-a-txt-file-entry-on-a-winform-ui)

```
    public static void getPermText(System.Windows.Forms.Form targetForm)
    {
        Stream fileStream = File.Open(dataFolder + PermFile, FileMode.Open);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream);

        string line = null;

        do
        {
            line = reader.ReadLine();
            string[] parts = line.Split('\n');

            if (line == null)
            {
                break;
            }

            try
                {

                int userCount;

                userCount = parts.Length;

                CheckBox[] chk = new CheckBox[userCount];
                int height = 1;
                int padding = 10;

                for (int i = 0; i <= userCount; i++)
                    {
                    chk[i] = new CheckBox();

                    chk[i].Name = parts.ToString();

                    chk[i].Text = parts.ToString();

                    chk[i].TabIndex = i;

                    chk[i].AutoCheck = true;

                    chk[i].Bounds = new Rectangle(15, 30 + padding + height, 150, 22);

                    targetForm.Controls.Add(chk[i]);

                    height += 22;

                    }
                }
            catch
                {
                }                

        } while (true);
    }
```

Unfortunately I'm not getting an error and I am getting a checkbox with the text "System.string[]" next to it. I'm pretty sure I'm only getting one. I noticed that I'm missing this statement from where I took the above from another part of the program (and from advice noted above and on my profile.)

```
        foreach (string parts in reader)
```

besides the variable errors I got that StreamReader does not have access to the GetEnumerator. I'm assuming that this missing foreach is why the for() statement is not incrementing.

That is the question. Why is this code not incrementing and why is it not putting the line, the username, from the text file where parts.ToString() is??

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?? I would really appreciate it. Thank you very much in advance. :-D

Comment: Remove your `catch` block so you can actually tell whether you get errors.

Comment: `chk[i].Text = parts[i];`

Comment: `parts.ToString()` -> `parts[i].ToString();`

Comment: @GrantWinney It's not that I'm asking you to do my debugging, which I am in fact doing in reality. I'm a newb. Proud of it. And you definitely pointed me in a good direction. Thank you. The userCount ref pointed me to the fact that the userCount is not incrementing because parts.Length is 1. I need that to increment. My guess is ReadLine()?? Thank You very much. :-D

Comment: You should check if the line is null before splitting it.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is because you trying to assign your `parts` which is array of string. Try that:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= userCount; i++)
                    {
                    chk[i] = new CheckBox();

                    chk[i].Name = parts[i];

                    chk[i].Text = parts[i];

                    chk[i].TabIndex = i;

                    chk[i].AutoCheck = true;

                    chk[i].Bounds = new Rectangle(15, 30 + padding + height, 150, 22);

                    targetForm.Controls.Add(chk[i]);

                    height += 22;

                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of issues I see:

1. You're reading a line from the file and then splitting it on new line, so you'll probably get only one element. You probably need to split the line on a delimiter, i.e. '-' or ','
2. You're setting `check[i].Name = parts;`. `parts` is a string array, so your checkbox only displays 'System.string[]'. Change that to `chk[i].Name = parts[i];`

Comment: Thank You. Please see my comment to @GrantWinney. I was thinking ReadLine(). I'll look at the split as well. Thank you very much :-D

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the code that works correctly. Should anyone like to comment on it I could certainly use the help. Thanks to everyone who helped and @Grant Whinney particularly.

```
    public static void getPermText(System.Windows.Forms.Form targetForm)
    {
        Stream fileStream = File.Open(dataFolder + PermFile, FileMode.Open);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream);

        string line = null;

            line = reader.ReadToEnd();
            string[] parts = line.Split('\n');

            try
                {

                int userCount;

                userCount = parts.Length;

                CheckBox[] chk = new CheckBox[userCount];
                int height = 1;
                int padding = 10;

                for (int i = 0; i < userCount; i++)
                    {
                    chk[i] = new CheckBox();

                    chk[i].Name = parts[i];

                    chk[i].Text = parts[i];

                    chk[i].TabIndex = i;

                    chk[i].AutoCheck = true;

                    chk[i].Bounds = new Rectangle(15, 30 + padding + height, 150, 22);

                    targetForm.Controls.Add(chk[i]);

                    height += 22;

                    }
                }
            catch
                {

                } 
          }
```

Essentially I dumped the do() statement, changed all of the parts.ToString() to parts.[i] (Sooo, SpellCheck can be circumvented. :-D) and changed line = reader.ReadLine() to .ReadToEnd(). It was incrementing, it just wasn't ever reading past the first line hence all check boxes had the same name.

Thank you Again to all that helped. I Trully Appreciate it!! Have an Awesome Day!! :-D